# Why when using this command in terminal on linux: "/usr/bin/time –v <filename>" do the times and values differ each time?

Tags: linux

When i run this command on Linux, why does do the times shown differ each time i run the command.
different values are return for the same file

Should it not be the same values each time?

Comment: It makes sense in practice only if your *program-filename* runs for more than a few seconds. And you should repeat it several times if you are benchmarking.

Comment: ok I understand, it was a question that I needed explained, why on earth am I being downvoted. Thank you to those who answered.

Comment: You have been downvoted because "your question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 2):

`time` gives you output that tells you something about how long a given command/program takes to run. This is of course very variable, as it's dependent on a lot of things, including, but not limited to, what other software is running and doing on your machine at the time you run `time` command.